# How to change file permissions of certain files?

Tags: linux

```
chmod u+x filename
```

I know this is the command for adding `x` to users, but I don't have a filename. I want to use this command for all files containing certain letters in their name. For example, i want to give perm to all files containing the letter `"o"`. How do I do it?

I tried combining it with find but no luck...

```
find . -name"*O**o*" chmod u+x
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but you need `-exec` as in `find . name "*o*" -exec chmod u+x {} \;`  See `man find` for details about exec.

Comment: as this doesn't appear to be a programming question, it may be better asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-i` to make the match case insensitive for your case.

```
find . -name -i "*o*" -exec chmod u+x {} \;
```